# How to plot multiple graphs into one using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have four separate datasets which all have the same x-axis:

```
x        y1    y2    y3    y4
12350  0.032  0.283 0.043  0.012
13200  0.234  0.229 0.934  0.002
15504  0.001  0.510 0.394. 0.294
17709  0.923  0.394 0.022  0.202
```

How do I enter this in ggplot? I can plot individual plots, but i'm not sure how to combine them. Adding the two plots below does not work:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y1)) + geom_line()
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y2)) + geom_line()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a plot with four curves.  You can transform the data frame from wide to long using any number of transformation functions.  Basically you want to end up with a data frame with three columns, one for the x values, one for the y values, and one with an identifier showing which of the original y's is associated with each x,y pair.

```
x     y     id
12350 0.032 y1
12350 0.028 y2
12350 0.043 y3
12350 0.012 y2
13200 0.234 y1
etc.
```

Then use the id group aesthetic to plot the curves individually.  If you do a search on "wide to long" you'll get lots of suggestions for exactly how to make the transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `data.table` package (use `install.packages('data.table')` if you don't have the package installed) this could be done like so:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

data_long <- melt(data, id.vars = 'x')

ggplot(data_long, aes(x = x, y = value, color = variable)) +
   geom_line()
```

`melt` will automatically generate the columns `variable` (containing the names of what where your columns y1-y4) and `value` (containing, you guessed it, the values).